# how to automatically sync elascticsearch with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose

I have a nodejs application that is backed by mongoDB with 10,000 documents.
I want to make available documents searchable, how do i automatically sync growing number of documents from mongoDB with elasticsearch

Comment: Use logstash  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-mongodb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/). Allows you to track all writes to the cluster and put them somewhere else. You have to be running a [Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) and MongoDB 3.6 or later.